# Split QStringList element into more elements

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have a `QStringList` with many elements, for example:

```
sl.at(i) = name:VAR1 size: 8 Decription:fdgag;
```

how can i split this line into more lines? I want to split line by line into more lines with for-loop.

thats what i have:

```
for(int i = 0; i != sl.size(); ++i)
{
   QString str = sl.at(i);
}
```

But then I don't know how I can split this...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split a string by space-character just use the function mentioned earlyer with space

```
QStringList split = str.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [QString::split()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split) functions:

```
for(int i = 0; i != sl.size(); ++i) {
    QString str = sl.at(i);
    // Split on , 
    QStringList splitStr = str.split(", ");
}
```

Comment: sorry i dont have a comma, i have a space character there

Comment: if i do this:
QString str = slOut.at(i);
                    strsplit = str.split("\\t+");

it doesnt work

Comment: Is it a single tab char between your strings?
If yes, then you need ("\t"), by using double slash you are escaping the slash which means a slash character followed by a t and a plus.
However, if you want to use a Regular Expression you need to make it clear to the function: str.split(QRegularExpression("\\t+"));